# import android support library with resources with IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-support-library, android-gradle-plugin

How can I import android support library with resouces into an android project in IntelliJ IDE.

I'm currenly using IntellJ13 and I have gradle installed on my computer. I have already checked the following but that doesn't work in Intellij

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: So, if you're using Gradle, did you add the dependency (e.g. `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"`) as instructed? Please post your `build.gradle` and any error messages you're getting.

Comment: yes I did, and I got Unknown Syntax. when creating a default android project, Intellij does not create a build.gradle file. my guess is I have problem configuring gradle on my project. (if it's related I'm using windows)

Comment: I think you should go through [IDEA's Android Gradle documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/android-gradle.html) ("Creating a Gradle-Android Project"). If you're still having problems, you could always try Android Studio which is basically the same IDE but specifically geared towards Android. With AS, it's extremely simple to add the support lib dependency.

Comment: Would you be able to use AndroidStudio instead of IntelliJ13?  I've been able to include the support library in AS projects without a problem.

Comment: If you don't have a build.gradle file in your project, then it must not be Gradle-based. Are you sure you don't need to add the support library in the ordinary IntelliJ way, not through Gradle?

Answer (score -1):

here's a step-by-step guide to import android support libraries in IntelliJ IDEA
http://aloyzije.blogspot.com/2014/01/importing-support-libraries-for-android.html